# EXC_RESOURCE -> photoanalysisd[815] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 130 MB (fatal)

Tags: ios, icloud, photos

On iOS 11.4.1 my iCloud Photos Library of ~60k photos never finishes generating the faces album. The device logs show that `photoanalysisd` is being killed by the kernel for memory violation after only a few minutes of phone locked on charger. I have left my phone locked and on charger overnight each night for the last 6 weeks.

The faces album reads:

```
Updating People...
To finish updating your people, lock your iPhone and connect it to power.
```

Relevant logs:

```
default 12:02:11.586901 -0400   photoanalysisd  PhotoAnalysis Agent is enabled
default 12:02:11.624508 -0400   photoanalysisd  Executive: background analysis asked to run at priority Maintenance, QOS label 9
default 12:02:11.626705 -0400   photoanalysisd  PhotoAnalysis is enabled. Bootstrapping photo library at /var/mobile/Media/PhotoData
default 12:02:12.152509 -0400   photoanalysisd  Coordinator: asking worker: 0x11a0380a0 to start job: <private>...
default 12:02:19.261692 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 11592784-BDB1-47AF-AD70-69F5D6D7CDAE/L0/070
default 12:02:19.269283 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 9740979E-D80C-434D-B9C5-24FAC3872D5D/L0/070
default 12:02:19.279286 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: F0DA9759-B1F9-4FD4-9F7A-75CDBF98F2B1/L0/070
default 12:02:19.288561 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 8E064BEC-4804-4083-A8D2-1655B433F732/L0/070
default 12:02:19.294883 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 1C23EED6-70B1-4A97-B591-1FBD8D6A72BB/L0/070
default 12:02:19.301833 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 7F03266D-F4F6-404C-BE65-894346BCD5A1/L0/070
default 12:02:19.308112 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 1F0F43EF-602A-4CA1-883F-4F7A71273AF3/L0/070
default 12:02:19.315416 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: B4FEB229-3A8A-42DA-BAF1-81D443486592/L0/070
default 12:02:19.324276 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: D006A157-3E11-4E62-9BB7-B0BABBCA8F88/L0/070
default 12:02:19.331180 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: DD5EF3BC-0135-44C0-A491-F05C3C6B9204/L0/070
default 12:02:19.337963 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 31A37DCC-EF58-44C2-8551-2EDD13CB5558/L0/070
default 12:02:19.343712 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 1B3F49B6-7CE1-43D1-836F-7B9B2B4F9A67/L0/070
default 12:02:19.359115 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: A3A6A0C5-9BDD-44E7-B72C-B9569286084C/L0/070
default 12:02:19.366395 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: AD749469-1560-45E2-BBA4-6363F133B138/L0/070
default 12:02:19.372795 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 86776744-5655-4B3F-A2FF-A08A49A887C6/L0/070
default 12:02:19.384344 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: A63D5D7C-129D-4CCD-A4C6-0655C07A2275/L0/070
default 12:02:19.396269 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 557760D3-44F7-4BC6-810B-C192EB147958/L0/070
default 12:02:19.408245 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: BC814AEC-EC1D-45F8-A81B-CCFB3ACD2F00/L0/070
default 12:02:19.421557 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: DD04BE89-90F1-4078-87D0-BDA2B2276B36/L0/070
default 12:02:19.435350 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 5CC3DD38-2ADF-4A38-BE0A-2D775C10E59D/L0/070
default 12:02:19.441113 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 085986E0-49A6-413B-AD97-60BCC3BF5575/L0/070
default 12:02:19.449010 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: 2114295F-B13A-44C0-89DD-1E449CEB9336/L0/070
default 12:02:19.456006 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: F4A0D5AA-BDC8-4814-A0AF-9EB806B19968/L0/070
default 12:02:19.464029 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: ABC25580-C169-41E7-AC88-233890DC59F7/L0/070
default 12:02:19.470593 -0400   photoanalysisd  Creating person with PHIdentifier: DCD33251-C56C-488C-A32B-8572040E5D83/L0/070
default 12:02:21.152185 -0400   photoanalysisd  Graph service worker graph diff computation completed, success=1, error=(null)
default 12:02:21.152680 -0400   photoanalysisd  Coordinator: Job finished: <PHAGraphServiceWorkerGraphUpdateJob 0x117d2b250 label='diff computation' created=2018-08-08 16:02:12 +0000>
default 12:02:24.573504 -0400   dasd    com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis:56B747:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Can Proceed, Score: 0.60}}
 ] sumScores:44.030000, denominator:52.030000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.846243}
default 12:02:30.213095 -0400   photoanalysisd  Coordinator: asking worker: 0x11a00ae80 to start job: <private>...
default 12:02:48.117908 -0400   dasd    com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis:56B747:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Can Proceed, Score: 0.60}}
 ] sumScores:44.030000, denominator:52.030000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.846243}
default 12:04:00.167610 -0400   dasd    com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis:56B747:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Can Proceed, Score: 0.60}}
 ] sumScores:44.030000, denominator:52.030000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.846243}
default 12:04:00.442317 -0400   symptomsd   Received CPU usage trigger: 
  photoanalysisd[815] () used 90.00s of CPU over 101.35 seconds (averaging 88%), violating a CPU usage limit of 90.00s over 180 seconds.
default 12:04:08.267801 -0400   dasd    com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis:56B747:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Can Proceed, Score: 0.60}}
 ] sumScores:44.030000, denominator:52.030000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.846243}
default 12:04:15.893083 -0400   dasd    com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis:56B747:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Can Proceed, Score: 0.60}}
 ] sumScores:44.030000, denominator:52.030000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.846243}
default 12:04:51.484693 -0400   kernel  EXC_RESOURCE -> photoanalysisd[815] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 130 MB (fatal)
default 12:04:51.485595 -0400   kernel  28525.077 memorystatus: killing_specific_process pid 815 [photoanalysisd] (per-process-limit 3) - memorystatus_available_pages: 54154
default 12:04:51.491655 -0400   UserEventAgent  Deferring XPC Activity: com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis
default 12:04:51.495521 -0400   dasd    CANCELED: com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis:56B747 <private>!
default 12:04:51.496428 -0400   ReportCrash Process photoanalysisd [815] killed by jetsam reason per-process-limit
default 12:04:51.499876 -0400   powerd  Process UserEventAgent.25 Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis" age:00:02:39  id:47244675855 [System: PrevIdle]
default 12:04:51.501512 -0400   powerd  Process photoanalysisd.815 ClientDied PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis" age:00:02:39  id:4295002896 [System: No Assertions]
default 12:04:51.501917 -0400   dasd    Submitted Activity: com.apple.photoanalysisd.backgroundanalysis:DD9FA3 <private>
default 12:04:51.619219 -0400   ReportCrash Formulating report for corpse[815] photoanalysisd
```

Comment: still have the same issue as of iOS 13