# How can I force the Photos app on my iPhone to recognize faces

Tags: ios, photos.app

I have a several photos in my camera roll, received mostly through WhatsApp in my iPhone XS.

In the photos, the person is in front of the camera and the face is completely visible and straight, not tilted, and when I swipe up to tag the person in the photo, I see a "No related found" message, it's not like it's mis-tagging, it doesn't find a face at all.

Selfies taken with the camera and photos taken from other places (downloaded from Facebook, for example) seem to be fine, the face is recognized, but Photos doesn't seem able to recognize the face in these photos from WhatsApp.

I have some photos of this person tagged and going to Photos > People to confirm additional photos doesn't find any additional photos.

Is there a way to force Photos to perform face recognition across the whole camera roll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know to force it perform face recognition is to open Photos, Lock the iPhone, plug it to the charger, and let it locked and plugged for some hours.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the iPhone is charging through a wireless charger? Because my iPhone stays locked and wirelessly charging for some hours everyday and face recognition does not kick in

Comment: Cannot tell for sure about wireless. Looking deeper about your problem I found another similar situation, which the face recognition was not performing, and was due to lack of memory. It is unanswered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333164/exc-resource-photoanalysisd815-exceeded-mem-limit-activehard-130-mb-fatal . It would be interesting if you could get a log from your iOS like the one on the above link, at least it would allow us to know if it is the same cause.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain those logs without a Mac? I don't have access to one

Answer (score 1):

I find this occurs with photos received via iMessage and other apps. I use the duplicate function to duplicate the photo. The Photo app is then able to recognise that there is a face in the duplicated photo.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different Windhover, it's great that you've responded to this question, but perhaps you could include a step by step guide or improve the answer to make this a more useful resource for others in future.